# C# HASH Algorithm logic for retrieved entry from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, algorithm, security, hash

I've been struggling with the logic on this one and how to get the HASH Algorithm to check that an entry retrieved from a SQL Server database matches an entry entered by a user.

The code below does work, what I can't get my head around is where the field retrieved from the SQL Server database should go in the code and how it can match with the entry entered by the user.

The code below does contain code for saving an amended HASH entry.

The entry in the SQL Server database is held as `Varbinary`

```
'0xD94C0F10760D83BC35C0786C674B5F8F'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    string[] passwordargs = new string[] { "turkey", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
        //If no file name is specified, write usage text.
        if (passwordargs.Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(usageText);
        }
        else
        {
            string pwd1 = passwordargs[0];
            // Create a byte array to hold the random value.
            byte[] salt1 = new byte[8];
            using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                // Fill the array with a random value.
                rngCsp.GetBytes(salt1);
            }

            //data1 can be a string or contents of a file.
            string data1 = "Some test data";
            //The default iteration count is 1000 so the two methods use the same iteration count.
            int myIterations = 1000;
            try
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes k1 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pwd1, salt1, myIterations);
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes k2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pwd1, salt1);
                // Encrypt the data.
                Aes encAlg = Aes.Create();
                encAlg.Key = k1.GetBytes(16);
                MemoryStream encryptionStream = new MemoryStream();
                CryptoStream encrypt = new CryptoStream(encryptionStream, encAlg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                byte[] utfD1 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false).GetBytes(data1);

                encrypt.Write(utfD1, 0, utfD1.Length);
                encrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
                encrypt.Close();
                byte[] edata1 = encryptionStream.ToArray();
                string encryptString = Convert.ToBase64String(edata1.ToArray());

                string queryStmt = "UPDATE [dbo].[Staff] SET [MEMWORD] = (@Content) WHERE STAFF_ID=7";

                using (SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDb"].ConnectionString))
                using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStmt, _con))
                {
                    SqlParameter param = _cmd.Parameters.Add("@Content", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
                    param.Value = edata1;

                    _con.Open();
                    _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    _con.Close();
                }

                k1.Reset();

                // Try to decrypt, thus showing it can be round-tripped.
                Aes decAlg = Aes.Create();
                decAlg.Key = k2.GetBytes(16);
                decAlg.IV = encAlg.IV;
                MemoryStream decryptionStreamBacking = new MemoryStream();
                CryptoStream decrypt = new CryptoStream(decryptionStreamBacking, decAlg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                decrypt.Write(edata1, 0, edata1.Length);
                decrypt.Flush();
                decrypt.Close();
                k2.Reset();
                string data2 = new UTF8Encoding(false).GetString(decryptionStreamBacking.ToArray());

                if (!data1.Equals(data2))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: The two values are not equal.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The two values are equal.");
                    Console.WriteLine("k1 iterations: {0}", k1.IterationCount);
                   

                    Console.WriteLine("k2 iterations: {0}", k2.IterationCount);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
                string error = e.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: A hash is basically only a string which you grab from the database and compare it with the hash value form the input

Comment: Be careful with matching. If the hashes don't match then the two originals don't match either. If the hashes do match, then it is possible that the two originals do not match. Hashing is not a one-to-one process, it is many-to-one. If the hashes match then you need to explicitly match the two originals as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean by

> The code below does work ...

`if (!data1.Equals(data2))` is equal when you expect it to be equal?

In my understanding you set `data1 = "Some test data"` and that will not change until we reach the end.

And for `data2` it's a little more work but break it down from top to bottom:

1. Store `data1` in `utfD1` as UTF-8 bytearray ->  `byte[] utfD1 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false).GetBytes(data1);`
2. Write `utfD1` into stream `encrypt` (`encryptionStream` is the underlying stream for CryptoStream) -> `encrypt.Write(utfD1, 0, utfD1.Length);`
3. Write `encryptionStream` int `edata1` byte array -> `byte[] edata1 = encryptionStream.ToArray();`
4. Write `edata1` into `decryptionStreamBacking` (because its the underlying stream of `decrypt`) -> `decrypt.Write(edata1, 0, edata1.Length);`
5. `decryptionStreamBacking` Decode UTF-8 byte array and store it in `data2` ->
6. `string data2 = new  UTF8Encoding(false).GetString(decryptionStreamBacking.ToArray());`

So for me it looks like a fancy way to say `string data2 = data1` and the database is a write only scenario. You only update one value in the database but you do not read anything from it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help and suggestions, we have got the working code down to this now.

We had to change
byte[] salt1 = new byte[8];
to
byte[] salt1 = new byte[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

Otherwise the salt1 would be different every time and this would create a different encryption which would not allow the entered password to pair against what is save in the database.

Thank you for everyone's input.

```
 byte[] returned_Data;
 string[] passwordargs = new string[] { "turkey", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
 //If no file name is specified, write usage text.
 if (passwordargs.Length == 0)
 {
 Console.WriteLine(usageText);
 }
 else
 {
 string pwd1 = passwordargs[0];
 byte[] salt1 = new byte[]{0,1 ,2, 3,4, 5,6, 7};
 using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCsp = new
RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
 {
 // Fill the array with a random value.
 rngCsp.GetBytes(salt1);
 }

 //data1 can be a string or contents of a file.
 string data1 = "Some test data";
 //The default iteration count is 1000 so the two methods use the same iteration count.
 int myIterations = 1000;
 try
 {
 Rfc2898DeriveBytes k1 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pwd1, salt1,myIterations);
 Rfc2898DeriveBytes k2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pwd1, salt1);
 // Encrypt the data.
 Aes encAlg = Aes.Create();
  encAlg.Key = k1.GetBytes(16);
 MemoryStream encryptionStream = new MemoryStream();
 CryptoStream encrypt = new CryptoStream(encryptionStream,
 encAlg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
 byte[] utfD1 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false).GetBytes(
data1);

 encrypt.Write(utfD1, 0, utfD1.Length);
 encrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
 encrypt.Close();
 byte[] edata1 = encryptionStream.ToArray();
                
 string queryStmt = "UPDATE [dbo].[Staff] SET [PASSWORD] = (@Content) WHERE STAFF_ID=7";

 using (SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString))
 using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStmt, _con))
 {
 SqlParameter param = _cmd.Parameters.Add("@Content", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
 param.Value = edata1;

 _con.Open();
 _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 _con.Close();
 }


 using (SqlConnection sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString))
 {
 sqlconnection.Open();

 string selectQuery = string.Format(@"Select [PASSWORD] From [dbo].[Staff] Where STAFF_ID={0}", 7);

 SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, sqlconnection);
 SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
 if (reader.Read())
 {
 returned_Data = (byte[])reader[0];
 string strData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(returned_Data);
 Console.WriteLine(strData);

  if(!edata1.SequenceEqual(returned_Data))
 {
 Console.WriteLine("Error: The two values are not equal.");
 }
 else
 {
 Console.WriteLine("The two values are equal.");
 Console.WriteLine("k1 iterations: {0}", k1.IterationCount);


Console.WriteLine("k2 iterations: {0}", k2.IterationCount);
                        }
                    }
                }
```